# Using the dense subset property and darboux's definition

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum, density-function

first off I would like to say that the solution in the picture is most likely incorrect since I didn't get full marks.

When the question refers to part a.) it's just referring to the darboux's def'n in the prev. question that I did not include in the picture.

Anyway, I need help understanding when I can use a dense subset. I feel like I don't really understand the concept and I'm just using it randomly. I know that my prof said that a dense subset can be used for reasoning when the range alternates from rational to irrational. Can anybody help? Thanks!

I also apologize for the ugly hand writing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that $m_{i}=\ln 1=0$, $M_{i}=\ln\sqrt{3}$ so $L(f,P)=0$, $U(f,P)=\ln\sqrt{3}$.

As @Berci has noted, there is also an issue on the $\sup,\inf$, they are numbers, not sets.

Comment: There's also an issue with the $\sup$ and $\inf$ written. They should be single numbers.

Comment: Oh... ok I see what you mean. I should've written the inf and sup to equal a single number, rather than the set. I also did not substitute my f(x) into the integral. Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

It is simple the fact that in every interval of a partition you will find an irrational number and a rational number (density), later you know, the upper sum for a partition P is always the same and not equal to the sup(lower sums)

Comment: Ah, so it doesn't differ much from what I already know. I'm not sure if I understand what you mean with the upper and lower sum. There are times when the inf(upper) and sup(lower) can approach that same value, yes?

Comment: Yeas there are times when they can approach the same vale but not this time. Thabks to density you always find a rational and a irrational number in the intervals of your partition. This mean that the maximun and minimun of f in this intervals are aleays the same and hence the upper and lower sums does not approach each other when we refine the partition, in deed, this sums are always the same! For all partition

Comment: ahhhh, a bit of miscommunication on my side xd, well thanks for letting me know!